# Excel find cell reference where answer was found

Tags: worksheet-function

Good morning

i have the following formula in L2:
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(MINIFS(B:B,C:C,J2),B:B,0))
It works perfectly but in some random cases it pulls in the incorrect data.
What is the formula to put in M2 to find the cell reference where the answer to the formula in L2 was found?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your initial formula itself - the part **MATCH(MINIFS(B:B,C:C,J2),B:B,0)** finds the relative position of an item in the array (column B in your case) that is given by MINIFS function. More information on the MATCH function is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60112&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Comment: I have the answer, I want to know in which cell in all my data did it find the answer.  I have seen the formula once but can't remember it

Comment: if you put `=MATCH(MINIFS(B:B,C:C,J2)` <-- in a cell what is the displayed value? | If it is 15, means the match is found at `E15`, if the value displayed is 7 ,  means the match is found at cell `E7`.  | take note take index match only shows the first match if there is multiple hits.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward to explain why your current set-up fails sometimes.

Imagine that cell `J2` contained "X" and that you had the following data in `B1:E10`:

|  | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 2 |  |  | E1 |
| **2** | 3 |  |  | E2 |
| **3** | 1 |  |  | E3 |
| **4** | 1 |  |  | E4 |
| **5** | 2 | X |  | E5 |
| **6** | 4 | X |  | E6 |
| **7** | 1 | X |  | E7 |
| **8** | 2 |  |  | E8 |
| **9** | 1 | X |  | E9 |
| **10** | 5 |  |  | E10 |

Your formula will incorrectly return "E3" here. Although the `MINIFS` part will correctly return 1, i.e., the entry in `B7`, when you then pass this to `MATCH` it will match it with the 1 in `B3`, despite that entry not having an "X" in column C.

The point is that there is nothing in your `INDEX`/`MATCH` set-up which says that the return from `MINIFS` should be matched against an entry which also has an "X" in column C, so if the return from `MINIFS` can also occur for an entry which *doesn't* have an "X" in column C, and which comes earlier in the table, you will return an incorrect answer.

You should be using, for example:

`=INDEX(E1:E10,MATCH(1,(B1:B10=MINIFS(B1:B10,C1:C10,J2))*(C1:C10=J2),0))`

which may require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, depending on your version of Excel. Note also that, with this version, it would be strongly inadvisable to use entire column references (`A:A`, `E:E`, etc.); hence my choice of an upper row reference of 10.